# Why is my git submodule command not working with Bitbucket?

Tags: git, git-submodules, bitbucket

I'm trying to add a submodule

https://bitbucket.org/hski/issuestats-public/wiki/Home

With the following command

```
git submodule add git@bitbucket.org:hski/issuestats-public.git issuestats
```

I'm getting the following error message

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Comment: Are you executing this command inside another git repository? If not, that is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is referring to your working copy - not the remote.

```
cd /no/git/here
git submodule add foo bar
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

You need to add submodules *to* a git repo

```
cd /my/repos/project-x
git submodule add foo bar
# will work or give a more specific error
```

If you just want to get the code so you can use it, you need to clone the repo:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/hski/issuestats-public.git issuestats
```